# Tire pressure for Tesla S 90D with 19" wheels, front & rear engines and air suspension

Tags: tire-pressure

Regarding my Tesla S 90D, the door label recommends a tire pressure of 45#, but Tesla information online suggests 50# for cars with 19" wheels, front & rear engines and air suspension which I have.  What is the correct air pressure for this configuration?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Can you please share a link to the online information you are referring to?

Answer (score 1):

https://forums.tesla.com/forum/forums/recommended-tire-pressure states 45psi for air suspension, 42psi for coil.

Unless the car has been modified, the door plate is the most accurate reference for this information on any car.

Comment: A site on Teslapedia confirms PeteCon's information assuming coil suspension has Michelin Primacy tires, but recommends 42 psi for coils/Goodyear Eagle RSA2 tires.

Comment: I can't find the site that recommended 50# but here's the Teslapediia site with detailed info: teslapedia.org/model-s/tesla-driver/tesla-model-s-tyre-pressures-uk-article/